# Why did my progress towards getting the Illuminator badge drop?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I have been tracking the [Illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator) badge for the last couple months on [my Activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197758/toolic?tab=topactivity). A few days ago, I saw the count increase from 291 to 292 (as expected) after I met [the requirements for the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-%E2%86%92refiner-%E2%86%92-illuminator) for such an increase.  I answered another user's question, made a *relevant* edit to the question, and someone upvoted my answer.

A day later, I was surprised when I noticed the count was back down to 291.  Why did the count decrease?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The count for the Illuminator badge can decrease if any of the requirements are **no longer met**.
There are several reasons for the count to drop.  The count will decrease by one when:

- The answer score drops from 1 to 0 due to such events as:

  - A new downvote
  - An upvote which has been retracted (undone)
- The question is closed for any reason (including as a duplicate)
- The question is deleted
- The answer is deleted

---

In this case, the Answer had a score of 1.  Then, according to the Question timeline, the Question was closed 4 hours later.  Once the Question was closed, the requirements of the Illuminator badge were no longer met, causing the count to drop.

---

Similarly, the count could increase again for this Answer if any of the actions which caused the decrease is reverted: a new upvote, re-open, undelete, etc.

---

See also, the [FAQ: Answer Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68258)